# Switch has two red wires

Tags: electrical, dimmer-switch

I am trying to replace a wall switch with a dimmable TP-Link Smart Wi-Fi Light Switch but when I got into the double gang box there were two reds, white and ground connected to the switch and all the black wires were connected by wire nut in the back. I had the TP-Link switch installed on a single gang switch and it worked beautifully but it that light isn't dimmable, so it wasn't needed there and I'd like to move it. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance [image][image]

Comment: Can you post a photo of the inside of the wall box please?

Comment: Are you opposed to sticking an extra box in the wall adjacent to this one?

Answer (score 1):

That's a three way switch.

In these pictures, it appears the red wire coming off the black terminal screw goes to the light, but you should confirm that.

Comment: NPM is correct. The top red and white wires go to the other 3-way switch as what they call "travelers". This enables you to switch the light from two locations. Your smart switch needs to be able to work with a standard 3-way on the other end.

Comment: The switch apparently does not support LEDs. I have four recessed LEDs that I was trying to use but the switch just powers them at 50% and then clicks off. Any recommendations on smart dimmers?